# How to layer Views so that 1 view overlays on top of another - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native project. When a user start to type in something in search, It will return results for autocomplete locations. When there are returned items, I want them to display and I want it to overlay the existing content that is displayed. I tried the `zIndex`, but it did not work. I am just trying to figure out a way to get it to overlay everything that exists.

Here is the code for the component that generates the results:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { TextInput, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'

import {Feather} from 'react-native-vector-icons'

import { SearchFilterContext } from '../../Context/SearchFilterContext'
import { PropertiesContext } from '../../Context/PropertiesContext'

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
const aspectWidth = deviceWidth - 16

const SearchComponent = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [autocompelete, setAutoComplete] = useState([])

  const {currentSearch, setCurrentSearch, results} = useContext(PropertiesContext)
  const {setResults, getProperties, setLoading} = useContext(PropertiesContext)

  const SubmitSearch = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    setCurrentSearch(search)
    setResults([])
    resetSearch()
  }

  const updateSearch = (value) => {
    setCurrentSearch(value)
    axios.get("https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/autocomplete", {
      params: {
        text: value,
        apiKey: "16753334b41a43a49890d07149c13eef"
      }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      response.data.features.map((feature) => {
        setAutoComplete(autocomplete => [...autocomplete, feature])
      })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    });
  }

  const resetSearch = () => {
    getProperties()
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.SearchBar}>
      <View  style={styles.SearchBarRow}>
        <View style={styles.search}>
          <Feather size={20} name='search'/>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={(value) => updateSearch(value)}
            value={currentSearch}
            placeholder='Enter City, State...'
          />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {SubmitSearch()}}>
          <Text style={styles.SearchText}>
            Search
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      {
        autocompelete.map(search => {
          console.log(search.properties.formatted)
          return(
            <View style={styles.resultContainer}>
              <Text>{search.properties.formatted}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        })
      }
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  SearchBar: {
    width: aspectWidth,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    display: 'flex',
    height: 32,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginTop: 8,
    borderRadius: 6
  },
  SearchBarRow: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 32,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginLeft: 8
  },
  search: {
    width: aspectWidth - 78,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingVertical: 8
  },
  input: {
    width: '90%',
    fontSize: 18,
    marginLeft: 6,
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  SearchText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#0039a6'
  },
  resultContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    paddingVertical: 4,
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 1
  }
})

export default SearchComponent
```

this is what it produces with items:
[image: image of current display]

Comment: Create a parent view and give him zIndex negative and give him positive which one you want overlay

Answer (score 0):

you need to add:

```
position: 'absolute'
```

and `zindex`

If there are multiple Views to overlap.